# Database connection with Nodejs in Angular SPA

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I need to create an Application using Angularjs, Angular material, Nodejs and database will be MySQL. I want to ask how Angularjs connect with MySQL database using Nodejs

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to use Nodejs as a server to expose the MySQL database data as responses to restful endpoints. To achieve this you'll need to learn/install express, and node-mysql.

Here is a [tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/)

Comment: I've tried this method to create connection getting the following error. Error: Module name "mysql" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])